# Ffmpeg: Is it possible to use -itsoffset option without transcoding for live RTMP streams?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, transcode

I am using `-itsoffset` option for delaying the video track of a live RTMP stream by few seconds but the problem is that I must use `-c:v libx264` or other codecs, I cannot use `-c:v copy`, I want to use copy to avoid transcoding, for local file it seems to be working for live streams it will fail if I use `-c:v copy`!

**Note:** all my input sources are RTMP URLs and I am outputting to a mpegts URL.

**Here is my full command**

```
ffmpeg -itsoffset 20.5 -i rtmp://mydomain.com:1935/app/stream1/key -i rtmp://mydomain.com:1935/app/stream2/key -map 0:a -metadata:s:a:0 title=en-US -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -map 1:a -metadata:s:a:1 title=es-ES -metadata:s:a:1 language=spa -map 0:v -c:v libx264 -f mpegts [https]://mydomain.com:443/stream/key/mpegts
```

Comment: It's working without transcoding. Example: `ffmpeg -itsoffset 1000 -i in.mp4 -c copy out.mp4`. Execute `ffprobe -show_frames out.mp4`, and see that the first frame has `pkt_pts_time=1000.000000`. What is the version of FFmpeg? What is the exact command you are using?

Comment: @Rotem thanks for your reply, I just updated my answer with full command.

Comment: Here is my Ffmpeg version is 4.3.4-0+deb11u1.

Comment: I don't think I can help you with that. In general `-itsoffset` doesn't require re-encodig, but I don't know about your specific case.